# Template Redirect Function Only Working When Logged In

Tags: functions, redirect, page-template, template-redirect

I added a `template_redirect` to my functions.php file, which redirects private staff members to a "Staff No Longer Available" page. However, my code only works when I am logged in. Am I missing something?

```
function redirect_private_staff() {
  if ( is_singular( 'our_providers' ) && 'private' == get_post_status() ) {
      wp_redirect( 'https://www.nystromcounseling.com/provider-profile-unavailable/', 301 );
        exit;
    };
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_private_staff' );
```

Comment: The fact that it only works when you're logged in indicates that caching is in play. Possibly a caching plugin? You'll probably need to flush it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, I agree with the comment from @vancoder that caching is likely at play here. If you're not sure how to purge the caching on your site, the easiest approach may be to add a simple query string on the end of the original URL. That usually bypasses caching and loads the page from scratch.

So if your original URL was https://www.example.com/our-providers/, then while logged out, enter this in your browser and see if the redirect works: https://www.example.com/our-providers/?cache-test=123456789

Note that `?cache-test=123456789` is what's added onto the end.

Also, manually setting up redirects through code can become cumbersome very quickly. I'd suggest one of two solutions here:

1. Utilize a plugin that allows you to add redirects in the admin. My favorite is [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), but there are a lot out there.
2. Check with your hosting provider to see if they offer a way to add redirects within their management tools. Most of the popular ones do.

Good luck!